# Is there a mapping between schema.org datasets and wikidata?

Tags: schema.org, wikidata

I am currently working on DBpedia datasets and would like to achieve the mapping between schema.org and DBpedia through wikidata. Hence I would like to know if there exists any mapping between schema.org and wikidata.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, I think, but there is some work in progress:

[Schema.org should have mappings to Wikidata terms where possible](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/280)

Comment: oh!.. So is there any alternate way to achieve the mapping from DBpedia to schema.org datasets if not through wikidata?

Comment: @Gita: No idea, sorry.